# How to install latest flash player for Iceweasel/Firefox

Tags: debian, firefox, adobe-flash, plugin, iceweasel

How does one install the latest version of Adobe's Flash Player for Iceweasel/Firefox?

Comment: Does https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

My solution is the following: go to Adobe's website and download the latest version (.tar.gz file): [download flash player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

Unpack the downloaded files:

```
tar xzvf /path/to/download/flash-player-archive.tar.gz
```

Copy the flash lib to your plugin directory:

```
cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

If Iceweasel (or Firefox) was already open, restart it.

Comment: So easy, and that's the only way it works with my environment ; it should be documented somewhere !

Comment: Works like charm :)